# Adding Row dynamically at multiple table LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

When I clicked `Add` button (below method is called)

```
 addSectionRecordRow(){
    this.skeyIndex+1;
    this.addSectionRecord.push({
       
            section:'', 
              sort:'',
              Question:[{

                question: '',
                sort : ''
               }]
     });
   }
```

its create rows every time when it clicked please check image

[image]

The problem is when i clicked on  `Plus` button to add more rows per  section (one Section  have  multiple rows)  these rows added to all section.Evertimes its create new row to all section by one click

```
addQuestionRow(){
     
        ++this.keyIndex;
      
       this.getQuestionRecord.push({
          question:'',
          sort:''
        })
```

let suppose i want  to add 3 rows in section 1 and 5 rows in section 2 so on . how its possible
Kindly chcek the code

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Coaching Template">
        <div class=" slds-var-m-around_small slds-box slds-theme_shade ">
         <div class=" slds-p-left_xx-large">
            <table>
         <tr>
             
             <td>
                 <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                 <lightning-input type="text" label="Name"></lightning-input>
                 </div>
             </td>
              <td>
                     <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                     <lightning-input type="text" label="Type"></lightning-input>
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
 
             <tr>
             
                 <td>
                     <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                     <lightning-input type="date" label="Start Date"></lightning-input>
                     </div>
                 </td>
                  <td>
                         <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                         <lightning-input type="text" label="Active"></lightning-input>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
             
                     <td>
                         <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                         <lightning-input type="date" label="End date "></lightning-input>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                      <td>
                             <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                                <template if:true={countryValues.data}>
                                    <lightning-combobox name="progress" label="Lead Source" value={value}
                                        options={countryValues.data.values} onchange={handleChange}>
                                    </lightning-combobox>
                                    </template>
                             </div>
                         </td>
                     </tr>
               
            </table>
       </div>
        </div>
        </lightning-card>
     <lightning-card  title="Question Template">
       
             <lightning-button  style="padding-right:110px ;" label="Add" slot="actions" onclick={addSectionRecordRow}>
             </lightning-button>
             <template for:each={addSectionRecord} for:item="sItem" for:index="index">
                 
                 <div key={sItem.id}>
             <div class=" slds-var-m-around_small slds-box slds-theme_shade " >
                 <div class=" slds-p-left_xx-large">
                   
                     <table>
                  <tr>
                      
                      <td>
                      <div class="slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                          <lightning-input type="text" label="Section"></lightning-input>
                          </div>
                      </td>
                       <td>
                              <div class=" slds-p-left_x-large slds-col slds-size_5-of-6">
                              <lightning-input type="text" label="Sort"></lightning-input>
                              </div>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                       
                          </table>
                          </div>
        
 
                         
 
             </div>
             
             <div class="c-container">
                 <template for:each={getQuestionRecord} for:item="item" for:index="index">
                 <lightning-layout horizontal-align="stretch" key={item.question}>
                     <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" size="5">
                         <div style="padding-left: 150px;margin-left: 60px;">
                             <lightning-input type="text" label="Question" onlcik={changeHandler} access-key={index} id={index} ></lightning-input>
                         </div>
                     </lightning-layout-item>
                     <lightning-layout-item padding="around-small" size="5"> 
                         <div style="padding-left:200px;"  >
                            
                             <lightning-input type="text" label="Sort" onlcik={changeHandler} access-key={index} id={index} ></lightning-input>
                         </div>
                     </lightning-layout-item>
 
                     <lightning-layout-item
                     size="1" >
                     <div class="slds-p-top_x-large">
                         <lightning-icon icon-name="action:new" 
                             alternative-text="Add Row" data-record-id={index}  size="small" title="Add Row" onclick={addQuestionRow}>
                         </lightning-icon>
                         <lightning-icon icon-name="action:delete" 
                             alternative-text="Delete Row" size="small" title="Delete Row"  access-key={item.id} id={index} onclick={removeRow}>
                         </lightning-icon>
                     </div>
                 </lightning-layout-item>
                     </lightning-layout>
                 </template>
                 </div>
                </div>
                </template>
         </lightning-card>         
         
         
         
  </template>
```

js

```
export default class CoachingTemplate extends LightningElement {
    
   
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: Coaching_Templates_OBJECT })
    contactInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues,
        {
            recordTypeId: '$contactInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
            fieldApiName: Country
        }
    )
    countryValues;


    skeyIndex = 0
    qkeyIndex = 0
   


    @track addSectionRecord = [
      {
        
           section : '',
           sort : '',
         
              
      }
    ];


  @track getQuestionRecord=
  [{
       question:'',
       sort:''
           
 }];
    addSectionRecordRow(){
    this.skeyIndex+1;
    this.addSectionRecord.push({
       
            section:'', 
              sort:'',
              Question:[{

                question: '',
                sort : ''
               }]
     });
   }


     addQuestionRow(){
 
        ++this.keyIndex;

       this.getQuestionRecord.push({
          question:'',
          sort:''
        })
        
       
    
  }
     
      
    changeHandler(event){
      console.log('changehandler');
  if(event.target.name ==="question"){
   
 this.getQuestionRecord[event.target.accessKey].question = event.target.value;
  }else{
    this.getQuestionRecord[event.target.accessKey].sort = event.target.value;
  }

  }
      
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have multiple variables to store the data separately. That means that addSectionRecord needs to have a property for the questions, and that needs to have a property for the answers.

Here's an example:

```
  nextSectionId = 1
  nextQuestionId = 1
  nextAnswerId = 1
  sections = [
    { 
      id: 0, 
      questions: [
        { 
          id: 0,
          answers: [
            { 
              id: 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The elements are then nested together:

```
<div for:each={sections} for:item="section" key={section.id} data-section-id={section.id}>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-p-horizontal_small">
        <lightning-input class="slds-size_10-of-12" label="Section" value={section.value} onchange={updateSection}>
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div for:each={section.questions} for:item="question" key={question.id} data-question-id={question.id}
        onchange={updateQuestion}>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning-input label="Question" value={question.value} class="slds-size_10-of-12" onchange={updateQuestion}>
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-grid slds-p-horizontal_large" for:each={question.answers} for:item="answer" key={answer.id}
            data-answer-id={answer.id} onchange={updateAnswer}>
            <lightning-input class="slds-size_10-of-12" label="Answer" value={answer.value} onchange={updateAnswer}>
            </lightning-input>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You then need to do recursive searches to find elements for updating each section, question, and answer.

I wrote a [complete demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/QxMCNnrro9cSpcwiulBq/src/app.js?p=stories) for you to check out.